# How to set generic Patameter T at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, json.net

I am using a custom JsonConverter. And I need to get type of an object and set in as generic parameter.

```
   public class PagedResultConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var pagedList = (IPagedList<T>)value;

            var jsonJObject = new JObject
            {
                {"TotalCount", pagedList.TotalCount}
            }

            jsonJObject.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
```

My `IPagedList<T>` parameter `T` will be type of `typeof(value)` But I can not set `IPagedList<typeof(value)>`

I need to get properties, members of interface.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can´t. As you allready noticed `T`is a *compile-time*-type, whereas you provide the actual type at *runtime*. How should the *compiler* know what you provide at *runtime*? However you may have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method

Comment: What are you  trying to accomplish? Probably there is another way to do what you want to do.

Comment: `typeof(value)` will always be `object` because it's compile time. What you probably mean is `value.GetType()`. Doesn't help with your problem though.

Comment: @nvoigt `typeof(value) ` won´t even compile.

Comment: @Kote I updated post, I need to access members of interface.

Comment: If you own `IPagedList<T>` - make it inherit non-generic `IPagedList` interface. Put `TotalCount` in that `IPagedList` interface, then you can just cast to `IPagedList` to get it. Otherwise - use reflection to get that `TotalCount`.

Comment: If you wanted `T` to be the type of `value`, i.e. `value.GetType()` then how could you *possibly* cast `value` to `IPagedList<T>`? Sounds more like `value` will be *some* `IPagedList<T>` for *some* `T` that is unknown to you. – Why don’t you make your `WriteJson` generic?

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned in the comment you can´t expect the compiler to infer a type you provide at *runtime*. That is when you know the actual type only when executing your program, how shopuld the compiler give you the right information on `pagedList` beforehand?

Maybe you can introduce a nin-generic interface that your generic one inherits from:

```
interface IPagedList { int TotalCount { get; set; } }
interface IPagedList<T> : IPagedList { ... }
```

Now you can cast the de-serialized instance to the non-generic interface:

```
var pagedList = (IPagedList)value;
```

However why don´t you make your `WriteJson`-method generic instead and provide the type via reflection:

```
public override void WriteJson<T>(JsonWriter writer, Tvalue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var pagedList = (IPagedList<T>)value;
}

var obj = ...
var m = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("WriteJson").MakeGenericMethod(obj.GetType());
m.Invoke(instanceOfMyClass, new object[] { myWriter, obj, myerializer });
```

Comment: He couldn't make `WriteJson` generic because then the converter won't correctly implement the abstract `WriteJson` from `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter`.